# Resharp Download file Async

Tags: download, async-await, restsharp

I can download the file by calling download method but it is not an async method. So I've tried ExecuteTaskAsync and waiting for the response (somehow it is blocked)

```
public async Task<byte[]> GetByteArray(string appName, Enums.DeviceType type, string version)
{
  RestClient client = new RestClient("http://localhost:443/api/versions/download");
  RestRequest request = new RestRequest();
  request.AddQueryParameter("version", version);
  request.AddQueryParameter("type", type.ToString());
  request.AddQueryParameter("appName",appName);

  var response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);

  if (response.ErrorException != null)
  {
    string message = "While downloading the file, an error occured";
    var exception = new Exception(message, response.ErrorException);
    throw exception;
   }

   return response.RawBytes; 
}
```

it stucks here `await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);`

but when I try it with the following code, I can get the response

```
  var t = client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
  t.Wait();
  var response = t.Result;  //await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

I call the method as follow

```
var arr = await GetByteArray(appName, type, version);
```

Comment: You must be calling `Wait()` or `Result` somewhere up the stack.

Comment: @PauloMorgado thank you for the comment. Yes "wait" keyword works but I would like to use "await".

Comment: There isn't a `wait` keyword. My comment meant that, for this to be happening, you must be calling `Wait()` or `Result` somewhere up the stack. Can you show the code calling `GetByteArray` and the code calling that and the code calling that and so on?

Comment: sorry wait is a function, I wrote wrong :) anyway I've made it with wait and reuslt.. it seems fine for now thank you